# Creating OPC server using Opc.Ua library - server not visible

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I'm trying to create OPC server using libraries from https://opcfoundation.org/ on this way:

```
public class OPCServer
{
    public void StartServer()
    {
        ApplicationInstance application = new ApplicationInstance();
        application.ApplicationName = "MyServer";
        application.ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Server;

        // load the application configuration.  
        ApplicationConfiguration config = new ApplicationConfiguration()
        {
            ApplicationName = "MyServer",
            ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Server,
            ApplicationUri = "urn:localhost:MyServer",
            ServerConfiguration = new ServerConfiguration
            {
                BaseAddresses = new StringCollection { "opc.tcp://localhost:4840/MyServer" },
                SecurityPolicies =
                {
                    new ServerSecurityPolicy()
                    {
                        SecurityMode = MessageSecurityMode.None,
                        SecurityPolicyUri = SecurityPolicies.None,
                    }
                },
            },
            SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
            {
                ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = "Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", SubjectName = "MyServer" },
                TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = "Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" },
                RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = "Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" },
                AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true,
                AddAppCertToTrustedStore = true
            },
            TransportConfigurations = new TransportConfigurationCollection(),
            TransportQuotas = new TransportQuotas { OperationTimeout = 15000 },
            ClientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration { DefaultSessionTimeout = 60000 },
            TraceConfiguration = new TraceConfiguration()
        };

        config.Validate(ApplicationType.Server).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (config.SecurityConfiguration.AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates)
        {
            config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Accept = (e.Error.StatusCode == StatusCodes.BadCertificateUntrusted);
            };
        }
        
        
        application.ApplicationConfiguration = config;

        // check the application certificate.  
        bool haveAppCertificate = application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 0).Result;

        if (!haveAppCertificate)
        {
            throw new Exception("Application instance certificate invalid!");
        }

        // start the server.  


        application.Start(new MySampleServer()).Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}

public class MySampleServer : StandardServer
{
    private BaseDataVariableState m_myVariable;

    protected override MasterNodeManager CreateMasterNodeManager(IServerInternal server, ApplicationConfiguration configuration)
    {
        List<INodeManager> nodeManagers = new List<INodeManager>
{
    new MyNodeManager(server, configuration)
};

        return new MasterNodeManager(server, configuration, null, nodeManagers.ToArray());
    }


    protected override ServerProperties LoadServerProperties()
    {
        ServerProperties properties = new ServerProperties
        {
            ManufacturerName = "My Manufacturer",
            ProductName = "My Sample Server",
            ProductUri = "http://my.sample.server.com/",
            SoftwareVersion = Utils.GetAssemblySoftwareVersion(),
            BuildNumber = Utils.GetAssemblyBuildNumber(),
            BuildDate = Utils.GetAssemblyTimestamp()
        };

        return properties;
    }
}

public class MyNodeManager : CustomNodeManager2
{

    private FolderState myFolder;
    private BaseDataVariableState myVariable;

    public MyNodeManager(IServerInternal server, ApplicationConfiguration config)
        : base(server, config, Namespaces.OpcUa)
    {
        SystemContext.NodeIdFactory = this;

        myFolder = new FolderState(null)
        {
            SymbolicName = "MyFolder",
            NodeId = new NodeId("MyFolder", NamespaceIndex),
            BrowseName = new QualifiedName("MyFolder", NamespaceIndex),
            DisplayName = new LocalizedText("MyFolder"),
            TypeDefinitionId = ObjectTypeIds.FolderType,
            EventNotifier = EventNotifiers.None
        };

        // Create a variable.
        myVariable = new BaseDataVariableState(myFolder)
        {
            SymbolicName = "MyVariable",
            NodeId = new NodeId("MyVariable", NamespaceIndex),
            BrowseName = new QualifiedName("MyVariable", NamespaceIndex),
            DisplayName = new LocalizedText("MyVariable"),
            DataType = DataTypeIds.Int32,
            ValueRank = ValueRanks.Scalar,
            AccessLevel = AccessLevels.CurrentReadOrWrite,
            UserAccessLevel = AccessLevels.CurrentReadOrWrite,
            Historizing = false,
            Value = 123,
            TypeDefinitionId = VariableTypeIds.BaseDataVariableType
        };

        myFolder.AddChild(myVariable);
    }

    public override void CreateAddressSpace(IDictionary<NodeId, IList<IReference>> externalReferences)
    {
        base.CreateAddressSpace(externalReferences);
        AddPredefinedNode(SystemContext, myFolder);
    }
}
```

But somehow the server is not created, only what I have is connection to localhost:4840

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?